# How to get the name of the file from request object in node js using code while sending the request through postman?

Tags: node.js, http, image-upload, req

I am trying to find the name of the file when sending a post request to a sample api server that is running locally.

The `req.body` object is huge and I am trying to send the file using `form-data` option from the body and selected a jpg image in the file selector.

Comment: files are attached to `req.files` which is an array.

Comment: I tried to print the req.files[0].name or may be req.files[0].filename to console but no result :(

Comment: what does console.log(...req.files) print to console?

Comment: I am not using express and multer. Can you provide a work around @jkalandarov